# Selecting a DOM Element when (auto-generated) HTML is not well formed

Tags: dom, xpath, jquery-selectors, getelementbyid

I'm trying to select a control in order to manipulate it but I'm having a problem: I can't select it. Maybe it's because the xml structure, but I really can't change it because it is externally created. SO I have this:

```
<span class="xforms-value  xforms-control xforms-input xforms-appearance xforms-optional xforms-enabled xforms-readonly xforms-valid " id="pName">
    <span class="focus">&nbsp;</span>
    <label class="xforms-label" id="xsltforms-mainform-label-2_2_4_3_">Name:</label>
    <span class="value">
        <input readonly="" class="xforms-value" type="text">
    </span>
    <span class="xforms-required-icon">*</span>
    <span class="xforms-alert">
        <span class="xforms-alert-icon">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

And what I need is to get the input (line 5). I tryed a lot, for example:

```
var elem01 = document.getElementById("pName"); 
console.log("getElementById: " + elem01);

var elem02 = document.evaluate(".//*[@id='pName']" ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );
console.log("evaluate: " + elem02);        
console.log(elem02.singleNodeValue); 

var elem03 = document.querySelector("#pName"); 
console.log("querySelector: " + elem03);
```

But none of that allows me to get a reference to the control. What's wrong?
With XPath, the problem seems to be the XML is no well formed, so document.getElementById("pName") doesnt return anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmzyqqja/7/

Comment: HTML does not need to be "well formed" to work in browsers. They can tolerate a lot of errors. Your only problem in your JSFiddle is trying to access the DOM elements before they have been created. Please see answer and JSFiddle below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example is that you are executing your Javascript before the relevant DOM elements are loaded (i.e. your code is in the `head` element):

This will fix the example:

```
window.onload = changeControlValue;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wmzyqqja/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var elem01 = document.getElementById("pName"); 
var inp = elem01.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
```

(in JSFiddle the "onload" setting is required.)

Comment: The thing is the xml is no well formed, so document.getElementById("pName") doesnt return anything.